# Sizing DataGrid to fit to its content when space available in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, size, height

I am new to WPF. I have got a `DataGrid` which is placed inside a `Grid` with row height set to `"*"` . I want this `DataGrid` height to fit to its content if the window height is not less than the total content height of the `DataGrid`, else show a vertical `ScrollViewer`. I have tried to surround it with a `StackPanel` which does the first job, i.e. resizing of the `DataGrid` height to fit to its content, but at a cost of not showing the vertical `ScrollViewer` which was appearing when the `DataGrid` was a direct child of the `Grid`. How I can achieve the required behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Grid` as parent container of your `DataGrid` and set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` for your `DataGrid`.

Hope it helps.